# How to put variable into quotes?

Tags: javascript

Would like to put the variable (  txt.txt.charAt(char_counter)  )in quotes.
Anyone can help?
Thanks

```
var pattern_node = document.createTextNode("Zeichen:"+txt.txt.charAt(char_counter)+" "+ str.str +" gesendet");
```

Comment: You could either use a template string `\`Zeichen: "${txt.txt.charAt(char_counter} gesendet\``, or add the strings by escaping the quote in the string (`"\""`) or use single quotes (`'"'`)

Comment: `var pattern_node = document.createTextNode('Zeichen:"'+txt.txt.charAt(char_counter)+'" '+ str.str +' gesendet');`

Answer (score 0):

ES6/ES2015 feature, [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
var pattern_node = document.createTextNode(`Zeichen:${txt.txt.charAt(char_counter)} ${str.str} gesendet`);
```